# Returning an [Out] array of struct in WCF function

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, struct, c++-cli

I have problems with returning an array of structs while a simple struct works flawlessly. Server side:

```
[OperationContract] long GetPapers([Out] array<PAPER_INFO>^% PaperInfo); -- FAIL
[OperationContract] long GetPaper([Out] PAPER_INFO% PaperInfo); -- SUCCESS
```

Client side:

```
[OperationContract] long GetPapers(out PAPER_INFO[] PaperInfo); -- FAIL
[OperationContract] long GetPaper(out PAPER_INFO PaperInfo); -- SUCCESS
```

By failing I mean no error message, just an empty array coming in. The struct is simple, only using simple types, no problems with serialization.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public value struct PAPER_INFO {
  unsigned int PaperWidth;
  unsigned int PaperLength;
};
```

Logging in the server and testing with WCF Test Client clearly shows that the array is populated, sent back, so the problem lies in the client side with the deserialization of the data. Although the struct above should work by itself as an inferred data contract, I also tried decorating it with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes, without any difference in behavior. Known types are used for a different purpose, but I tried them too, just in case, with no difference, either.

What could make the array problematic and not the struct itself?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `array<PAPER_INFO%>^` instead of `array<PAPER_INFO>^%` ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't think so: "the element type of a cli::array must be a handle or value type".

Comment: So this PAPER_INFO is your cli type? then try with `array<PAPER_INFO^>^`?

Comment: I can't yet see how to populate it then. But adding a hat to an explicitely value struct?

Comment: No, it wasn't the C++ side at all. It was a data contracting issue, after all.

Answer (score 0):

It was a data contract issue after all. I don't know why because the inferred contract should work all right, it needs an explicit name, anyway:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, Pack = 1)]
[DataContract(Name = "PAPER_INFO")]
public value struct PAPER_INFO {
  [DataMember] unsigned int PaperWidth;
  [DataMember] unsigned int PaperLength;
};
```